Legendre transformation is a continuous map
I was reading an article about the Legendre Transformation in Convex Analysis.
It was defined like this:

Let $\varphi$ be a  continuous function on $\left[0,\infty\right)$ and convex on $\mathbb{R}_{> 0}$, we defined the function $\varphi^{*}$ on $\left[0,\infty\right)$ as :
$$
\forall\ \lambda \in \left[0,\infty\right),\quad
\varphi^{*}\left(\lambda\right) := \inf_{x\ \in\ \left[0,\infty\right)}\left[\lambda x + \varphi\left(x\right) - \varphi\left(0\right)\right]
$$
$\varphi^{*}$ is so called the Legendre Transform of the function $\varphi$.

So my question is : is $\varphi^{*}$ continuous?

If I recall correctly,  the Legendre transform of a convex function is again a convex function and therefore continuous on any open interval.

Do you have a proof of the convexity of the Legendre transformation? Or a source?

Here is a proof that the Legendre transform is convex. Though I am used to a slightly different version of the definition of Legendre transform. With your definition the transform is concave. I will ignore the $-\varphi^{*}(0)$ since it is immaterial. Since convex/concave functions on open intervals are continuous this answers the question on the open interval.
\begin{align*}
\varphi^{*}(t\mu+(1-t)\nu) &= \inf_x\{(t\mu+(1-t)\nu)x+\varphi(x)\} \\
                       &= \inf_x\{t(\mu x+\varphi(x))+ (1-t)(\nu x+\varphi(x))\} \\
                       &\geq \inf_x\{t(\mu x+\varphi(x))\} + \inf_x\{(1-t)(\nu x+\varphi(x))\}  \\
                       &= t\varphi^{*}(\mu)+(1-t)\varphi^{*}(\nu)
\end{align*}
Using $\inf_x\{f(x)+g(x)\}\geq \inf_x\{f(x)\}+\inf_x\{g(x)\}$.

Thanks a lot ! :)
